# How do i store a file with machine code into an array

Tags: c, virtual-machine

How would i store any type of file with text ex. sasm, mach(for machine code) etc.
I dont want to have to write it like this and put it directly into the array https://ttm.sh/hPS.png
i want to be able to take text from a file with text on it like this

```
0x1000
0x30C3
0x11FC
```

and store that into the array program[] and have a new line be a new spot into an array

Comment: `xxd` has an option to get a hexdump of a file and output it in the form of a C header file containing an array.

Comment: If loading it from a binary file isn't possible, write something to convert it into valid C code instead, either some kind of script (Perl, Python, Node.js, etc.) or a smaller precursor C program that runs before the main compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
unsigned program[] = {
#include "program.mach"
};
```

With program.mach looking like:

```
0x1000,
0x30C3,
0x11FC
```